# Checkbox laravel collective valores separados por comas

Tags: mysql, laravelcollective

porfa me ayudan 
Tengo este formulario en laravel collective que contiene 10 checkbox donde se deben seleccionar los tipos de licencias de conducir de una persona

{{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence', 'B', false, ['class'=>'filled-in']) }} B
        
    
    
        
            {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence', 'C', false, ['class'=>'filled-in']) }} C
        
    
    
        
            {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence', 'D', false, ['class'=>'filled-in']) }} D
        
    
    
        
            {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence', 'E', false, ['class'=>'filled-in']) }} E
        
    
    
        
            {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence', 'F', false, ['class'=>'filled-in']) }} F

En la base de datos tengo un campo varchar que se llama driver_licence que debe guardar lo chequeado en este formato :

`A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B, C, D, E, F`

Pero aun no entiendo como  tendría que hacerlo para guardar esto (store), y también para mostrarlo posteriormente en(en la vista datoenrolamiento/{id}/edit)

En el edit mi controlador (EnrollmentdataController<) estoy enviando los datos de esta forma

`$file = File::orderBy('id','ASC')->where('person_id',$id)->get();
    return view('datoenrolamiento.edit')
        ->with(compact('file'));
    }`

y con la variable `$file[0]->driver_licence` recibo los datos de la base de datos que en este caso ingrese manualmente `A1, A2, A3, A4, A5, B, C, D, E, F`

Comment: Si no sabes como te esta llegando la información puedes hacer un dd($request->all()) y puedes verlo, ciclas los valores y los guardas en la base de datos

Answer (score 2):

revise el código y lo implemente en base de datos, con una tabla pivote que guarda los checkbox seleccionados por el usuario y funciona.
$driverlicences es un arreglo que contiene todos los tipos de licencia.
$driverlicencefiles tiene los dato de la tabla pivote de las licencias seleccionadas.

El modelo Driverlicence contiene los campos description y su id
El modelo File contiene el campo description y su id y  tabla pivote "driverlicence_files" que tiene los campos id, driverlicence_id, file_id.

Y estoy actualizando la informacion de esta manera

$file->driverlicences()->sync($request->get('driver_licence'));

Pero el problema es posterior a tener seleccionados los campos en la misma vista solo me muestra los campos que estan chequeados y no me muestra los otros campos que no fueron chequeados

Esto tengo en la vista

`@foreach($driverlicences as $driverlicence)
    
        
            @foreach ($driverlicencefiles as $driverlicencefile)
                @if($driverlicencefile->driverlicence_id == $driverlicence->id)
                    {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence[]', $driverlicence->id, $driverlicencefile->driverlicence_id == $driverlicence->id ? true : false, ['class'=>'filled-in']) }} {{ $driverlicence->description }} 
                @endif
            @endforeach
        
    
@endforeach`

Answer (score 2):

Al final lo hice asi

```
@foreach($driverlicences as $driverlicence)
    @if (count($driverlicencefiles) > 0 )
        <?php $estado = false;
        ?>
            @for ($i = 0; $i < count($driverlicencefiles); $i++)
                @if($driverlicence->id == $driverlicencefiles[$i]->driverlicence_id)
                    <? $estado = true; ?>
                @endif
            @endfor
            @if($estado == true)
                <label>
                    {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence[]', $driverlicence->id, true) }}
                    <span>{{ $driverlicence->description }}</span>
                </label>
            @else
                <label>
                    {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence[]', $driverlicence->id, false) }}
                    <span>{{ $driverlicence->description }}</span>
                </label>
            @endif
    @else
        <label>
            {{ Form::checkbox('driver_licence[]', $driverlicence->id, false) }}
            <span>{{ $driverlicence->description }}</span>
        </label>
    @endif
@endforeach
```

Pero no se si existirá alguna otra forma mas optima para realizarlo